# 'Cannot reference Exe projects' and unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

We had a unit test project (exe, using NUnitLite) that referenced the main application to unit test code within the main application (an exe).

This used to work, but now Xamarin is giving an error that we can't reference an exe project.

Why is this?
What alternatives do people suggest for unit testing application code?  It seems wrong to have to move all application code from the exe to an assembly just for the purposes of unit testing.

Comment: It should work. What's exactly the error message being given ? One *common* thing, that does not work, is having the same .exe and with another .dll (or two .dll or two .exe). That would give the same strongname and can't be processed correctly.

Comment: We have a solution with exe, multiple assemblies, and unit test project.  In the unit test project if we edit references and go to the projects tab, the exe project is grayed, cannot be ticked, and the project name has ' (Cannot reference Exe projects)' appended.

Comment: Duncan, have you solved the problem? I have the same issue now and can't find how to fix it.

Comment: Nope.  I gather it is a limitation imposed by iOS.  Refer https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the feature was accidentally removed :-( Someone must have overlooked that valid, if uncommon, scenario. Please file a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) on Xamarin.Studio and request this feature to be **re**enabled.

Until then I see two workarounds:

1. Build/execute the tests from a script (e.g. a Makefile). You can [automate](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/touch-unit-automation-revisited/) this to require less steps than using the IDE;
2. Add a pre-build step to your project to make a copy of the .exe and name it .dll. Then reference this copy of the assembly.